# Primefaces filterBy and sortBy are empty and EL not being evaluated

Tags: jsf, primefaces, jsf-2

I am simply putting my Primefaces column tag inside a tagged wrapper like the following, however, the sortBy and filterBy EL expressions are not being calculated properly and not being passed on to the load method in my LazyModel.

Basically, I have the following tag ex:column:

```
<ui:composition
xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"  
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
xmlns:ang="http://ang.com/jsf/facelets">

<p:column headerText="#{label}" sortable="#{sort}" sortBy="#{property}" filterBy="#{property}" filterable="#{filter}" filterMatchMode="#{filterMatchMode}">
    <h:outputText value="#{property}" />
</p:column>
```

In my main piece of code I am doing the following:

```
<p:dataTable id="mainTable" widgetVar="tblTable" var="c" 
      value="#{applicationBean.lazyModel}" lazy="true" 
      paginatorTemplate="{FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {CurrentPageReport} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown}" 
       paginator="true" rows="10" style="margin-bottom:20px" 
       selectionMode="single" selection="#{applicationBean.selected}"
       paginatorPosition="bottom" rowKey="#{c.id}">

      <ex:column label="First Name" property="#{c.firstName}" 
          filter="true" sort="true" filterMatchMode="contains" />
```

However, when my method load data is being called in my Lazy Load bean, the sortBy and filterBy column are being passed as "property" instead of "firstName".

```
public List<T> load(int first, int pageSize, String sortField, SortOrder sortOrder, Map<String,Object> filters)
```

Any ideas why the EL expression is not being calculated in the filterBy and sortBy inside a tag?

Just for your info, the column is rendered properly. I can see all the content inside the table, however when I click to sort or filter I get the exception that property does not exist.

I tried to play with the field="#{property}" instead of sortBy and filterBy, however, it just works 
for the sortBy; filter by is still coming empty when I use the field attribute.

Comment: Try to split your property into `bean` and `field` to prevent EL to be evaluated as you pass it to your component. In your XHTML use `bean="#{c}" field="firstName"` and in your component use `sortyBy="#{bean[field]}"`.

Comment: Jasper, observe that the Bean does not hold the field itself. It is the var derived from the table. Even though, I tried. The method load is receiving now the string "bean[field]". The expression is still not being evaluated. XHTML: bean="#{c}" field="firstName"; Component: filterBy="#{bean[field]}" --> load is called with String = bean[field] instead of evaluating the EL expression. I also tried filterBy="#{field}" and my method receives the String "field" instead of "firstName".

Comment: Jasper, using your idea, I got the following answer: 1-split the var and the field name; 2-insert the field name in the field variable. XHTML: var="#{c}" field="firstName"; Component: field="#{field}" sortBy="#{field}" filterBy="#{field}" . The "field" is the most important piece here; if you don't use it, it won't work.

Answer (score 0):

## Solution

Make sure your tag use the 3 elements: field, sortBy and filterBy; all these elements just receive the name of the field and not the var/bean.

**XHTML:**

```
<ex:column label="First Name" var="#{c}" field="firstName" 
     filter="true" sort="true" filterMatchMode="contains" />
```

**Component:**

```
<p:column headerText="#{label}" field="#{field}" sortBy="#{field}"
    filterBy="#{field}" sortable="#{sort}" filterable="#{filter}"
    filterMatchMode="#{filterMatchMode}">
        <h:outputText value="#{var[field]}" />
</p:column>
```